# NLog log commits are not in sequence

Tags: vb.net, nlog

I am logging using NLog and there are times when it is not really accurate.  When I am doing many commits in the same second (or within several seconds), it seems to be off.

I know how the program logs and in what sequence.  I've put some 'start' and 'stop' texts in there to make sure.. but when I look at the file I will see stuff after 'stop' that should have been before.

Are there any controls on how fast the information can come in or how it is queued to print to the file?  I would think it would just work, but it definitely isn't :(

Comment: I think it is because I have multiple targets :(  When I run .Info I use a different layout than when I use .Debug.  Because of that I think it is not perfectly sequential.  My 'Starts' and 'Stops' are a different layout to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this one... I had multiple layouts going to the same file (in order to segregate the file into sequential sections).  Because of that (and because of the speed at which I log during debug mode) the 2 layouts didn't quite log sequentially.